# We are out of new [design]s

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

[design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design) has 17,597 questions as of this writing, 1,360 of which are [closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdesign%5D%20closed%3Ayes).

According to my favourite search engine, [the definition of design is](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=definition%20design):

> To conceive or fashion in the mind; invent.

---

Following [Shog9's procedure from MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392):

1. #### Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   It does not describe the content of the question whatsoever, because it is *incredibly* ambiguous.
   The term "design" can be applied to literally any decision made in any circumstance. It can be about OOP inheritance trees design, UI, database tables, system architecture, ...
2. #### Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   Well, this is so ambiguous that at least part of that tag has to be.
3. #### Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   This tag means "Some decision has to be taken / thought of". This can be said of every single question that is asked on Stack Overflow. No meaningful information whatsoever is added by this tag.
4. #### Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   No. There are too many meanings in too many contexts to pinpoint one specifically.

---

I do not think there is any way to replace that tag with any other.
[design] adds no information to questions and really should disappear.

A close friend of that tag is [design-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns) (21,233 questions) with 2,252 [common questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design%20design-patterns?mode=all). Re-tagging some questions with that tag should be discussed.

Please do not discuss [design-patterns](http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2016/04/08/fing-patterns/) here and instead focus on [design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design) itself. If you wish to discuss [design-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns), please ask a new Meta question.

---

Please note that burninations are not just tag removals - They are the process of carefully moderating a specific place of Stack Overflow. Avoid mass-editing the tag out of questions as it is counter-productive. For more information, see [Shog9's answer on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/306392) or the [official burnination process](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination).

Comment: The main problem is that many people uses [design] instead of [design-patterns] and there are another bunch of people who use [design] as UX, but should be posting the question in UX.SE instead. However, there a few legitimate questions for example: [design] [android].

Comment: @Zanon It is interesting that you have a specific example of a legitimate combination of tags using [design]. Could you elaborate? Note that you can do that in an answer.

Comment: Picking the [first result](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design%20android?mode=all),  [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36514574/android-studio-how-to-make-a-2-column-linearlayout) seems fine regarding tags. Though, just my opinion. [android] [design] try to find experts in Android development that can implement a specific design/layout objective.

Comment: @Zanon That question would be _way_ better off with [[tag:user-interface]] than with [design]. Here, [design]'s ambiguity strikes again: Is it about UI design? Application design? Data management design? There is nothing this tag adds to that question or the few others I have checked like it.

Comment: Stats before featuring: 4 answers (chronological) Answer 1 +20/-1 Answer 2 Deleted Answer 3 +3/0 Answer 4 +1/-2  Views 1322

Comment: Question is +106 / -4

Comment: @Luuklag That question is clearly off-topic. There's a big difference between closing an off-topic question and mass-editing tags. Starting to edit out tags before approval isn't permitted, but you're always allowed to close off-topic questions (even in tags that are being considered for burnination).

Comment: Oh damn.  I've learned the hard way that I need to pay attention to these burninations to prevent answers I've supported for many years from getting destroyed.  I got a *lot* of [design] answers, "why does it work this way" questions are interesting.  Sigh.

Comment: @HansPassant If you have an objection to burninating this tag, you should add an answer to that effect. You can also feel free to re-tag stuff that's still on-topic and ought to be preserved if this gets approved.

Comment: @HansPassant With 21k questions, I'd say we're only gonna burn this for a week before letting CMs bulk remove the tag. The likelihood this hits anything of yours is fairly low. For comparison [code-review] had 1.3k questions and still took 3 weeks to fully burn.

Comment: @HansPassant you are more then welcome to help out in the burnination. Feel free to edit the tag out of good quality questions that are not too-broad or asking for an off-site resource. That is, once the burnination starts.

Comment: I have contributed 16K quality posts already, they don't need to be deleted to improve site quality.  That [code-review] burnination got notably absurd at the end, there doesn't seem to be a reliable "good enough" trigger.

Comment: @HansPassant It looks like [only 16 of your posts have this tag](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A17034+%5Bdesign%5D) - it's easy enough to just manually edit the tag out in those cases to make sure that none of your posts are accidentally deleted if that's your main objection.

Comment: @HansPassant I undeleted and reopened it. Any others? Who was the user? Which room socvr or the burnination rooms?

Comment: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=1836109

Comment: @HansPassant I'm not sure I would've deleted that because I think that your answer provides useful information (in fact, I've upvoted it), but the question itself should be closed because the OP is kind of asking us to test the code for him.

Comment: @Machavity [Homework] was a 20k question tag at the time we burned it.  IIRC we were at it manually for at least a month closing awful stuff before any automated tools were ran to remove the tag from the presumably worth keeping rump.

Comment: @DanNeely: I spent a week burninating value. I am unwilling to lift a finger for this one.

Comment: @YvetteColomb It seems like this has a decent consensus around it - should it be advanced?

Comment: @YvetteColomb Do you know how much longer we'll be burninating this?

Comment: I just noticed the design-patterns link points to a comic about RegEx. [face-palm]. And here I'd thought the repeated mis-tagging was due to the [pattern] synonym.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica it is alive again, 17 questions

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

Given the gigantic size of this tag, the burn will be initially time boxed to one week. If, after a week, progress is still steady and the community is still interested in continuing work on the tag, the deadline will be extended. Following that, the CMs will remove the tag from the system.

For that reason, it may be worthwhile to target the questions which were not very well received first.

- [Negatively scored questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bdesign%5D+is%3Aq+closed%3Ano+score%3A..-1&mixed=0)
- [Negatively & zero scored questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=%5Bdesign%5D+is%3Aq+closed%3Ano+score%3A..0&mixed=0)

## Progress:

The [design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=design),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdesign%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdesign%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdesign%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdesign%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track the progress of burnination](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182583)

[image]
Thanks to [g00glen00b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1915448/g00glen00b) and [Jon Clements](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1252759/jon-clements) for setting up [Gemmy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8300708/gemmy) to guide us in burning this large tag.

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". Editing is best left to users with [full-edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 48):

Per the tag's own wiki (emphasis mine), the tag is purely opinion-based:

> Design in programming is the act of **making particular choices about how best to structure a program**, to achieve goals of reliability, maintainability, correctness or ease of use.

We should burninate it.

Questions could conceivably exist with only this tag, but such questions would, by the very description of the tag, be opinion-based. In other words, close-worthy. Other, more specific tags such as [design-patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-patterns) and [responsive-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/responsive-design) exist already, so we won't even be losing much useful tagging context.

PS - We should probably lump [design-rationale](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design-rationale) (15 questions) in with this.

Comment: // , I have voted this down, because your answer fails to demonstrate that the phrase you emphasized, "making particular choices about how best to structure a program", necessarily implies that the tag is purely opinion based. Making particular choices does not mean making them on mere subjective preference alone, hence the existence of the Software Engineering Stack Exchange. The correctness or incorrectness of a design can be shown. Is this overlap undesirable in itself?

Comment: @NathanBasanese What's correct or best for a particular design is always dependent on a myriad of factors, which includes opinion most of the time. If you consider the approach that there is likely always an objectively better design given all possible considerations for each scenario, then it's not POB... but it is absurdly too broad.

Answer (score 11):

This tag should definitely be burninated. The third result in the [design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design) search already had nothing to do with "design" (at least as of my search). Additionally, the tag is so broad that any question that could somehow fit itself to the tag would likely be closed as "too broad" as well.

Answer (score 9):

I'm in two minds about this burn. I have no issue with the tags ambiguity and the face that it could do well being split into several tags. The concern is the closure and deletion of content in the attempt to remove the tag, when a retag would suffice.

Removing a tag != removing content. It does give reviewers a chance to close vote on questions, however it's important not to lose sight of the fact that we're removing a tag and if in doubt, retagging should be the goto, not closure and deletion.

This is something we need to be particularly mindful of with tag with so many posts, it can be overwhelming and in the effort to remove the tag it's important to remember and maintain the goal of it's remove the tag not content.

We will need to rely heavily on the community team (Shog) to conduct this burn, should we proceed.

Comment: I think the propper way to go about this is to close any off-topic stuff, and then have the tag mass-removed from all posts.

Comment: @Luuklag: Are you willing to go through a significant fraction of 21k even if we could remove the close vote limit for burnination?

Comment: I like to believe I've contributed a significant amount to the last burn. I'd be willing to do the same again if my time allows me.

Answer (score 4):

20k+ questions is a lot of questions (and answers) to review. I suggest we ask a community manager to remove the tag altogether and blacklist it. A retagging effort would be massive.

Certainly the tag could be replaced with other tags, but I don't see how this could be viably applied in bulk.

Comment: I agree, but first let us take a week or two to rid this honeypot from off-topic questions whilst they are still in the pot.

Comment: @Luuklag they're not going anywhere, there's a lot of off topic posts. The thing that concerns me is that questions are closed unnecessarily in pushes to burn tags or hit the close review queue. It's a symptom of how overwhelming the task is vs the tools the users have to deal with it.

Answer (score 3):

This should definitely be burninated.

Questions about software design are more suited for [Software Engineering Stack Exchange.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

I'd argue that programming and design are 2 different things.

Comment: That was my thought too, actually - if something really is a pure design question it should go to Software Engineering SE instead, since that's the site designated to receive that type of question.

Answer (score 3):

Design really identifies a stage in a project, the stage between analysis and development.  It does not identify the topic that the project addresses.  It could be information technology, or some sub topic within IT.  It could be agriculture, or industry, or architecture.  Design affects them all.

I've had problems with questions under [database-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-design) and that tag is considerably more specific than [design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design)  in general.

Part of the problem is that it's very hard to tell whether two questions concerning design are really duplicates or not.  On the surface,  the two questions can appear to be totally unrelated to each other.  There is no reason for the asker to recognize the prior question as the same as the question the asker is about to ask.

However, there is a design principle, insight, or technique that makes the two questions look like fraternal twins, if not identical twins.  It's obvious to the person with the answer that they are duplicates.  But it's not obvious at all to the person without the answer.  So the same question gets asked over and over again, in different guises.

At least, that's my experience with [database-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/database-design).  I 
Expect the same is true of [design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design)

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion design should really be burninated. From what i see many of the questions are about so many topics (and many about graphical design or web design) meaning that the spectrum of what can be asked with this tag is too wide, and many of the topics may not be relevant for stackoverflow.

Maybe if someone tries to use the tag we could show some options of other stack exchange sites or suggest other tags (like design-patterns, code-structure, database-design)?

An example:

- For graphical design related questions, please try:
  https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/
- For user experience, interaction and webdesign questions, please try:
  https://ux.stackexchange.com/
- For software and algorithm design related questions, please try:
  https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/
- Also try more meaningful tags as design-patterns, code-structure, database-design, project-structure...

Answer (score 0):

I just want to point out there is also a [software-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software-design) tag. Perhaps the same arguments made for burning this tag apply to that one; or perhaps some *design* questions should be tagged with *software-design* instead.

There is also a [code-design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-design) tag, which appears superfluous.

Answer (score -3):

> [...] every single question that is asked on Stack Overflow.

This is *manifestly* not true.

A question asking [Why is it faster to process a sorted array than an unsorted array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11227809/why-is-it-faster-to-process-a-sorted-array-than-an-unsorted-array/11227902) is not a design question.

A question asking [How to delete a localStorage item when the browser window/tab is closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943220/how-to-delete-a-localstorage-item-when-the-browser-window-tab-is-closed) is not a design question.

A question asking how one can [Hide strange unwanted Xcode logs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37800790/hide-strange-unwanted-xcode-logs) is not a design question.

[How do you tell git to stash the index only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5281663/how-do-you-tell-git-to-stash-the-index-only) is not a design question.

[C++ zero initialization - Why is `b` in this program uninitialized, but `a` is initialized?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54350114/c-zero-initialization-why-is-b-in-this-program-uninitialized-but-a-is-i) is not a design question

Figuring out why a [Dictionary infinite loop is exiting unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54316557/dictionary-infinite-loop-exiting-unexpectedly) is not a question of design.

I can go on... Actually, questions about design are fairly uncommon around here.

> > **Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**
>
> No.

You're contradicting yourself, because right above that you said

> This tag means "Some decision has to be taken / thought of".

which is overly vague but essentially correct. Earlier,

> It can be about OOP inheritance trees design, UI, database tables, system architecture

Right, and in all those domains, "design" does indeed mean the same thing: **defining the interaction of the components under consideration**. The fact that the type of components differs does not make the word "ambiguous", as you say, it just makes it an *abstraction* (and the abstraction makes it a useful word).

> It does not describe the content of the question whatsoever

Yes, it does. It says that the question is about this particular thing that concerns programmers while they're working on code,  just like [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/performance) or [debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugging) does.

Someone might argue that it's (walking the line of being) a meta tag, -- one which describes the question *itself* rather than the contents of the question (for example, [novice-level], [poll], or [unclear]). But like [performance], it does not actually fail that test.

---

The burnination checklist responses here are handwavy and are themselves nearly as vague as they claim the tag is.

## This tag should not have been removed.

It served a useful purpose in marking questions that are about **decisions regarding interfaces and component interaction in code**, while writing that code.

At worst, it applies to questions that might be better-suited for the [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) site, but that doesn't make them *inherently* off-topic here.

Answer (score -10):

With 17,000+ questions, that's a pure bot cleanup or not at all.

I'm really in favor of not at all at this point.

Comment: 21k today... this is an old question now =)

Comment: With a dedicated effort it can be dealt with in a few months. Such a high number of question actually indicates a human touch will be needed *more* than a lower-use tag, as there'll be way more edge cases to handle.

Comment: @TylerH Personally, I prefer blacklist first (don't fight against the tide) and then careful chipping.

Comment: @Braiam personally I'd prefer it just be [bulk removed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/375801/3956566) and move onto the next.

Comment: @YvetteColomb: I don't mind the negative votes because I started the right debate.

Comment: @Joshua I upvoted this. :)

Comment: By that logic, we could never burninate a tag with lots of questions no matter how bad the tag was.