# Filter out questions I've flagged in search

Tags: support, flags, search, data-explorer

[The [design] tag is being burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320690/the-design-tag-is-being-burninated)

I have enough reputation to edit posts directly but I'm below the threshold for close votes, so I can only flag for closure.

Is there a way for me to filter out questions I've already flagged? There doesn't appear to be a built in option for this in the [advanced search options](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching) but is there an existing query I should be using? It would be nice to not keep seeing a post I can't do anymore with.

Comment: It's not in the data explorer, but I think that the API has nodes for it.

Comment: Something I do personally that might help is run a user script that changes the visited link colour to something more obvious.