# Blacklist the [design] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, blocklist-request

The [design](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/design) was recently [burninated](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/320690/we-are-out-of-new-designs) but just today I've seen it on at least a couple of new questions. It seems very likely this will continue and it won't disappear for long without help so suggest it is blacklisted.

Comment: Never should have been removed in the first place. What a ridiculous waste of time.

Comment: @JoshCaswell yeah, we should have seen that this would happen and should have blacklisted it, not just burninated.

Comment: Right now searching shows no questions tagged[design]. They may have been removed since this post was listed on 'hot meta posts'

Comment: I still see none. Hopefully whoever's removing them can keep it up until the Tag Roomba arrives.

Comment: @JoshCaswell the burns are my least favourite thing on the site. They're exhausting and there's usually always fall out

Comment: As long as [this page returns 404](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/design/info), the tag doesn't exist. Need to keep a lokkout tho

Comment: @JoshCaswell  Out of curiosity why shouldn't it have been removed?

Comment: Answered below, @opa

Comment: It would help if you had included the tag definition (before it got deleted), since this is a pathologically broadly-named tag whose name could mean almost anything to all people, and said name could be misconstrued to apply to nearly 100% of SO. If it was only supposed to apply to e.g. 'class-interface-design', then it should have been named that. Even 'interface-design' would have been overly broad and would have been misapplied to UX, GUIs and lots of other unintended things.

Comment: This tag is alive again, there are 17 questions

Answer (score 4):

This has been completed:

[image: image displaying the system warning displayed when a user attempts to use the "design" tag]

Answer (score -23):

This tag should not be blacklisted. As I have explained on the burnination post, [it never should have been removed in the first place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379483/603977):

> It served a useful purpose in marking questions that are about **decisions regarding interfaces and component interaction in code**, while writing that code.
>
> At worst, it applies to questions that might be better-suited for the [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com) site, but that doesn't make them *inherently* off-topic here.

We should **permit its use** on appropriate questions again.

Here are some examples of appropriate questions for the tag:

- [Is extending UIViewController to access the app delegate an antipattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54540087/extending-uiviewcontroller-to-access-appdelegate-an-antipattern)
- [Centralized token for concurrent asynchronous network tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54541766/centralized-token-for-concurrent-asynchronous-network-tasks)

Comment: How could we enforce that it only gets used on "appropriate questions"? Or, more specifically, what examples you can provide that are "appropriate questions" that are on topic for SO and doesn't apply any other tag?

Comment: The community burninated it a little over a month ago - it would be strange for us to say that this tag is OK at this point.

Comment: Changing a policy decision is impossible, @EJoshuaS?

Comment: @EJoshuaS hey, we can, collectively, make mistakes. Heck, probably most of the time we would. But Josh doesn't offer any concrete reason why we made a mistake.

Comment: I did, in the linked answer, @Braiam.

Comment: @EJoshuaS: It was burninated because it was an unsalvagable mess. If it weren't for the natter attraction it would be brought back shortly. We could perhaps bring it back under a long name.

Comment: https://ux.stackexchange.com seems like a much better place for design questions than Software Engineering (or the main SO site.)

Comment: Yes, @DanielBeck, Graphic Design is definitely off-topic here. "Design" in the context of a programming website means _programming_ design.

Comment: UX also doesn't mean graphic design, but I take your point.

Comment: @JoshCaswell I guess we technically *could*, but it seems a little weird to change course so soon after making the decision unless we have a really, really good reason (especially since you only objected to the burnination after the fact, not while we were actually considering it).

Comment: Design questions should be on topic here. Programming is not only about debugging things...

Comment: Design questions _are_ on topic here. And we should have a tag for them.

Comment: _"objected to the burnination after the fact"_ This argument makes no sense to me: if the decision is wrong, it should be disregarded. It doesn't matter when it happened. Unless there's some cost to changing now. Which I don't see. In fact, there's _less_ cost, because no-one has to monitor the tag and keep removing it.

Comment: I find it very odd that my linked answer in reply to the burnination proposal has been downvoted much much less than this one...are people not clicking through?

Comment: Either that or people don't necessarily think that it's worth voting twice on what basically amounts to the same proposal. Besides, it's not like we're going to unburninate the tag at this point.

Comment: It is highly unlikely that linking to the same arguments that failed to convince people to not burninate the tag is going to convince people to not blacklist the tag. If you want to convince people that this is an acceptable tag you are going to need to come up with a new argument and evidence to support it.

Comment: My answer to the burnination post was made well after the removal had been completed, @JoeW. The two answers are actually contemporaneous.

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to post that as a new request rather then an approved and completed request?

Comment: I'm not sure, @JoeW. My only proposal is that we should allow the use of the tag going forwards -- i.e., not blacklist it, as suggested by this question. I'm certainly not trying to say someone should go back and replace the tag on every post from which it was removed.

Comment: A major part of the problem with the design tag is that it's ambiguous as to what it means in different contexts and to different people. If you want a tag that indicates the concept behind the questions you provide as examples, then use a tag that is more specific to exactly what those questions cover. "design" is just *way* too broad an area to really be a reasonable tag. Can someone be an expert in "design", definitely not. They can be an expert in a specific type of design (i.e. something that has a *much* smaller scope).